# How to have an array of authorized readers in a graphql schema?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, authorization, aws-amplify

On aws with schema below it allow to dynamically add/remove owners on a record.

Is it possible to have the same with readers?

I'd like to let owners choose which readers are allowed to access a particular record.

```
type ToDo
@model
@auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "owners"}])
{
    id: ID!
    content: String
    owners: [String]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on: - [GraphQL Authorization Schemas for AWS Amplify](https://iamondemand.com/blog/6-graphql-authorization-schemas-for-aws-amplify/)

Here is a tested solution that works:

```
type ToDo 
@model
@auth(rules: [ # owner-based authorization
    { allow: owner }, # defines that the creator of the todo is authorized to read, edit, and delete it
    { allow: owner, ownerField: "readers", operations: [read]} # defines that all users in the readers field of the todo have permission to view it
])
{
    id: ID!
    content: String
    readers: [String] # String array to configure multi-readers authorizations
}
```